# Shifting beamer overlay specifications e.g. with an environment

Tags: beamer, environments, overlays

I regularly reuse very complex content from one beamer talk in another. Often, in the new talk the timing is different, so I would have to change all overlay specifications. This would amout to changing dozens if not hundreds of numbers by hand.

Is there a way to do this more easily? Here is what my dream solution would be:

Lets say I have the following code block:

```
\item<4-> lalala
\item<5-> lululu
\item<6-> lololo
```

I would like to be able to write something like this

```
\begin{overlayshift}{-2}
   \item<4-> lalala
   \item<5-> lululu
   \item<6-> lololo
\end{overlayshift}
```

and end up with the same behaviour as if I had written

```
   \item<2-> lalala
   \item<3-> lululu
   \item<4-> lololo
```

Can this be done somehow? Thank you very much!

Comment: Ideally, nested shifts would be additive, to allow for reusing of reused content, etc.

Comment: I have no direct experience with this but you can give an explicit offset. Have a look at Sec 9.6.4 of the `beamer` doc.

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware of that possibility, and as far as I understand it does not what I want. Or is there some trick to repurpose it?